# How many cards are needed to have all so all the cards have 10 different pictures and each card has exactly 3 pictures in common with any other card

Tags: graph-theory, card-games

How many cards are needed to have all so all the cards have $10$ different pictures and each card has exactly $3$ pictures in common with any other card and each picture shows up an equal amount of times.

I want to make a card game like **Spot It!** where you say $3$ pictures instead of $1$. I don't understand how the people who made **Spot It!** could do this with $8$ pictures. what method do I use to make it work for any amount of pictures in common. we could think of this as a graph I think so this might have something to do with graph theory.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about Dobble?

Comment: We can use a cyclic difference set where every number appears 3 times. said in this video here about the math of Dobble/Spot it! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTDKqW_GLkw